# Why does this python statement give this output?

Tags: python-3.x

```
for i in range (1, 5):
    for j in range (1, 3):
        print (i*j, end= " ")
```

output= 1 2 2 4 3 6 4 8

I cannot understand how this output is worked out, can someone please break this statement down for me please?

Comment: Values of i in the Outer loop: 1,2,3,4. Values of j in the Inner loop j: 1,2. For each value in the outer loop all values in the inner loop are used. Resulting in: 1*1, 1*2, 2*1, 2*2, 3*1, 3*2, 4*1, 4*2

Comment: @LuckyJosh:  Next time, post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about Python nested for loops in [W3Schools website](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp)